# Don't change the reference to a collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" while changing properyt in an entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting above exception when i tried to change the value of an property in the entity but not the collection.

I retrieved value by tinyUrl even though it is not an primary key in the table.

Below is part of the code snippet

```
Sample sample = retrieveContentByUrl("https://text.com");
sample.setDescription("Sample");
getSession().saveorupdate(sample);
```

Sample.java

```
class Sample {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="TINY_URL")
    private int tinyUrl;

    @Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="sample",fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<TextBooks> textBooks = new HashSet<TextBooks>();

    //Having getters and setters for all above variables
 }
```

TextBooks.java

```
 class TextBooks {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID")
    private Sample sample;

    //Having getters and setters for all above variables
 }
```

.hbm file

```
<class name="com.sample.Sample"
        table="SAMPLE" >
        <id name="id" column="ID" type="long">
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
         <property column="TINY_URL" name="tinyUrl" />
        <property column="DESCRIPTION" name="description" />
        <set name="textBooks" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
            <key column="ID" />
            <one-to-many
            class="com.text.TextBooks" />
        </set>
</set>
</class>
```